# Fetch all fitness data at once

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

From the official Facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness) you can get simple statement that you can *fetch* 3 types of `fitness` activities:

- `fitness.bikes`
- `fitness.walks`
- `fitness.runs`

That's great but they all share the same fields and there's no possibility to distiguish which one was fetched besides the `graphPath`.
I need all of this data and ideally I want to fetch it all at once but if I create a method like this:

```
let walkRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/fitness.walks", parameters: nil)
let runRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/fitness.runs", parameters: nil)
let bikeRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/fitness.bikes", parameters: nil)

var connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

connection.addRequest(walkRequest) { (connection, result, error) -> Void
    //
}

connection.addRequest(runRequest) { (connection, result, error) -> Void
    //
}

connection.addRequest(bikeRequest) { (connection, result, error) -> Void
    //
}

connection.start()
```

I get three different callbacs, returning same data and somehow I have to merge this into one structure so I can send it to the backend.
I'd like to get a `Dictionary` with structure similiar to this:

```
[
    "walks": [ JSON ],
    "runs": [JSON],
    "bikes": [ JSON ]
]
```

**Is it possible to create a batched request like this? Or do I have to do it manually with 3 different `FBSDKGraphRequest`s and just wait for them to finish?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the so-called field expansion:

```
GET /me?fields=fitness.bikes,fitness.walks,fitness.runs
```

As I unfortunately have no such data in my account, I can't test the result, but the query runs smoothly.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to get... Do you know if it's possible to return only `course` for each?

Comment: Yeah, work but I only get `id`. Is it possible to get everything for each `course`? Just like calling `/me/fitness.bikes/course`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just take all data, and select the course field in the client?

Comment: I think that's the only possibility 